# How to grant access to a file to only one user

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, authorization

I'm having a problem how to resolve this scenario in JavaEE 6 (Webprofile).

I have a group of users with a certain role, who can trigger the generation of an image. The access to these images is restricted by role (Superuser).

The problem is, that a user with the role "Superuser" has the potential rights to access an image generated by another user with that role.

The filename is randomly generated and the image is deleted after a short period. But the image contains sensitive data, so I want to restrict access to it as much as possible.

**Is there a way to limit access to an image/file only to the user who created it?**

web.xml, which so far, only restricts access to the folder of the images by role:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Images</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Superuser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Servlet filter that checks which user is logged in before serving the file.
In that filter you should also check the destination (which file), check file's owner, then check if current user matches the owner.
More about filters here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html
Another useful resource: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm